# XML data extraction using PHP simpleXML

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to retrieve XML data from XML file and when I use children() I expect it will retrieve data of sub nodes but its not retrieving. In the following XML file

```
<Notes>
    <Note id="f1" type="foot" display="1">
        <P>The second respondent by virtue of the extended definition of “foreign state” in s 3(3) of the Act.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f2" type="foot" display="2">
        <P>
            <Pubref>[<Year>1965</Year>] <Series>VR</Series><Pages>204</Pages></Pubref>.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f3" type="foot" display="3">
        <P>Ibid, 206.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f4" type="foot" display="4">
        <P>
            <Emph type="i">Foreign State Immunity</Emph>, ALRC 24, (1984).</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f5" type="foot" display="5">
        <P>Ibid, 55, [93].</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f6" type="foot" display="6">
        <P>Macquarie Dictionary (5th ed, 2009), 1475.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f7" type="foot" display="7">
        <P>Ibid, 727.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f8" type="foot" display="8">
        <P>
            <Emph type="i">Foreign State Immunity</Emph>, ALRC 24, 1984, p xviii, [17] and p 51, [90].</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f9" type="foot" display="9">
        <P>
            <Pubref>(<Year>2011</Year>) <Vol>192</Vol><Series>FCR</Series><Pages>393</Pages></Pubref>.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f10" type="foot" display="10">
        <P>Ibid, 437.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f11" type="foot" display="11">
        <P>
            <Pubref>(<Year>2004</Year>) <Vol>185</Vol><Series>FLR</Series><Pages>48</Pages></Pubref>.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f12" type="foot" display="12">
        <P>Ibid, [108].</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f13" type="foot" display="13">
        <P>(2005) 12 VR 340, 346.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f14" type="foot" display="14">
        <P>
            <Pubref>[<Year>1987</Year>] <Vol>1</Vol><Series>Qd R</Series><Pages>221</Pages></Pubref>.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f15" type="foot" display="15">
        <P>
            <MNCit>[2008] QCA 328</MNCit>.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f16" type="foot" display="16">
        <P>
            <Pubref>[<Year>2013</Year>] <Vol>1</Vol><Series>Qd R</Series><Pages>204</Pages></Pubref>.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f17" type="foot" display="17">
        <P>[1955] AC 72.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f18" type="foot" display="18">
        <P>
            <Pubref>(<Year>1988</Year>) <Vol>17</Vol><Series>NSWLR</Series><Pages>623</Pages></Pubref>.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f19" type="foot" display="19">
        <P>
            <Pubref>(<Year>2010</Year>) <Vol>79</Vol><Series>NSWLR</Series><Pages>513</Pages></Pubref>.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f20" type="foot" display="20">
        <P>[1955] AC 72, 87.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f21" type="foot" display="21">
        <P>Ibid, 89–90.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f22" type="foot" display="22">
        <P>
            <Pubref>(<Year>1988</Year>) <Vol>17</Vol><Series>NSWLR</Series><Pages>623</Pages></Pubref>, 630.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f23" type="foot" display="23">
        <P>
            <Pubref>(<Year>2010</Year>) <Vol>79</Vol><Series>NSWLR</Series><Pages>513</Pages></Pubref>.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f24" type="foot" display="24">
        <P>
            <Pubref>(<Year>1988</Year>) <Vol>17</Vol><Series>NSWLR</Series><Pages>623</Pages></Pubref>, 633 per Cole J cited in <Xref ref="cr11" role="cr"><Name><Emph type="i">Zhang v Zemin</Emph></Name><Pubref>(<Year>2010</Year>) <Vol>79</Vol><Series>NSWLR</Series><Pages>513</Pages></Pubref>, 524</Xref>.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f25" type="foot" display="25">
        <P>
            <Pubref>[<Year>1983</Year>] <Vol>1</Vol><Series>AC</Series><Pages>244</Pages></Pubref>.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f26" type="foot" display="26">
        <P>
            <Pubref>(<Year>2012</Year>) <Vol>247</Vol><Series>CLR</Series><Pages>240</Pages></Pubref>.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f27" type="foot" display="27">
        <P>
            <Pubref>[<Year>1983</Year>] <Vol>1</Vol><Series>AC</Series><Pages>244</Pages></Pubref>, 262.</P>
    </Note>
    <Note id="f28" type="foot" display="28">
        <P>At [23].</P>
    </Note>
</Notes>
```

I used the following PHP code to get print this data

```
$fileloc = "../qjfiles/c2014-2.001.xml";
$filedata = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($fileloc));
foreach ($filedata->Notes->children() as $filexmldata) {
    echo $filexmldata->children()."<br/>";
}
```

The output is displaying as follows

```
The second respondent by virtue of the extended definition of â€œforeign stateâ€ in s 3(3) of the Act.
.
Ibid, 206.
, ALRC 24, (1984).
Ibid, 55, [93].
Macquarie Dictionary (5th ed, 2009), 1475.
Ibid, 727.
, ALRC 24, 1984, p xviii, [17] and p 51, [90].
.
Ibid, 437.
.
Ibid, [108].
(2005) 12 VR 340, 346.
.
.
.
[1955] AC 72.
.
.
[1955] AC 72, 87.
Ibid, 89â€“90.
, 630.
.
, 633 per Cole J cited in .
.
.
, 262.
At [23].
```

How can I display the output of `<Note id="f1"` separately and `<Note id="f2"` separately?

I tried like `$filexmldata->Note[1]->children()` but it didn't work

Comment: Is there any specific reason to go with xml file, json is light weight then xml?

Comment: @bablu - We have large Gigs of data in XML, as of now, we need to process the existing XML files.

Comment: @bablu Yes, there are plenty of reasons. "Light weight" is not always the most important consideration, and JSON isn't automatically better than XML for every job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to that question

```
How can I display the output of <Note id="f1" separately and <Note id="f2" separately?
```

You can use the xpath method. Here is an example on how to get the node containing id="f2" :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$node = $xml->xpath('/Notes/Note[@id="f2"]');
```

Comment: I am getting error `Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object`

Comment: in your case you have to modify like this $filedata->xpath('/Notes/Note[@id="f2"]');
this code works perfectly. I tried it also

Comment: But how to display Children() items?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your php code can you please replace below and try

```
 <?php
$fileloc = "../qjfiles/c2014-2.001.xml";

$filedata = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($fileloc));

    foreach ($filedata as $filexmldata) {
        foreach($filexmldata->attributes() as $a=> $b) {
             echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
        }
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($filexmldata->P);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try this. It works for me. $a will be the key and $b will be the values. Check about foreach() loop

Comment: It's generally a good idea to include an explanation in your answer of what your code is doing and why. This makes it easier for readers to apply the general approach to their own code, rather than just copying something they don't understand.